# Writing a Formula/Script conditional on Multiple Threshold Values & Applying it Over Many Rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, excel-formula

I am trying to write a formula or script that would take two inputs, a student's Attendance and GPA and spit out their On-Track rating as described here.

[image: on-track-matrix]

[My Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l_3vnZhmtk6WkKGKbTOFO00XnRbuSzfwC6RUNDkdi98/edit?usp=sharing)

```
function ONTRACK(Att, GPA){

  function getAttendanceRow(number){
    if(number>=98){row="A";}
    else if(number>=95){row="B";}
    else if(number>=90){row="C";}
    else if(number>=80){row="D";}
    else {row="E";}
    return row
  }

  function getGPACol(number){
    if(number<1){col="F";}
    else if(number<2){col="G";}
    else if(number<3){col="H";}
    else {col="I";}
    return col
  }

  var matrix=getAttendanceRow(Att) + getGPACol(GPA)

  var matrix_hash={'AI':5, 'BI':5, 
                   'AH':4, 'CI':4, 
                   'AG':3, 'BG':3, 'BH':3, 'CH':3, 'DI':3,
                   'BF':2, 'CF':2, 'CG':2, 'DG':2, 'DH':2,'EH':2, 
                   'DF':1, 'EF':1, 'EG':1 }
  return matrix_hash[matrix]

}
```

**TWO QUESTIONS**

**1. How do I apply this across large amount of rows without getting the timeout error?**

I've tried to use setFormula

```
function makeN(){
    ss.getRange("N2").setFormula("=ONTRACK(G2*100,H2)");
    ss.getRange("N2").copyTo(ss.getRange("N2:N"+lastRow));
}
```

I've also played around with the map method as suggested my the documentation, but get an error about the first element being undefined. I'm not familiar with the map method, so my problem could lie there.

```
function ONTRACK2(input){
  if (input.map) {         // Test whether input is an array.
    return input.map(ONTRACK2); // Recurse over array if so.
  } else {
    // do actual function work here
    return ONTRACK(input[0][0]*100, input[0][1])

  }
 };
```

Something similar works for GPA, where I'm calculating GPA without an error:

```
function GPA2(input){
  if (input.map) {         // Test whether input is an array.
    return input.map(GPA2); // Recurse over array if so.
  } else {
    // do actual function work here
     return myAverage(getPoints(input[0][0]), getPoints(input[0][1]), getPoints(input[0][2]), getPoints(input[0][4]))

  }
};
```

The other script-based idea would be to build some kind of array object through iteration that stores the "On Track" values and then writes them to the correct column.

**2. Can this be done without AppScripts, as a in-Sheets formula instead?**

I was playing around with the fuzzy lookups referenced [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=184546)

I made a Reference Table

[image: ontrack reference table]

These are the formulas I've tried, where Columns G and H are my Attendance and GPA respectively.

```
=INDEX('Reference Table'!F2:F20,MATCH(2,INDEX(1/(('Reference Table'!D2:D20=G2)*('Reference Table'!E2:E20<=H2)),0)))

=ArrayFormula(INDEX('Reference Table'!$F$2:$F$20,MAX(ROW('Reference Table'!$D$2:$D$20)*(('Reference Table'!$D$2:$D$20)=G2)*(('Reference Table'!$E$2:$E$20)<=H16))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure about the sheet formula, but you can do this with apps script.

Go to [your sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l_3vnZhmtk6WkKGKbTOFO00XnRbuSzfwC6RUNDkdi98/edit?usp=sharing), on the menu, click "Find students Track" and "Calculate track". Column "P" will fill with students track data. Voila!

This is my function

```
function FindMyTrack()
{

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var student = ss.getSheetByName("StudentData");//select sheets
  var refer = ss.getSheetByName("Reference Table");//select sheets
  var stData = student.getRange(2, 7, student.getLastRow(), 2).getValues();// get sheet data
  var refData = refer.getRange('D2:F20').getValues();// get sheet data
  var tracks = [];
  //checking each student attendance and GPA with reference data
  for(var n in stData ){ 
    for(var p in refData){ 
      if( stData[n][0] >= refData[p][0] && stData[n][1] >= refData[p][1]){
        tracks.push([refData[p][2]]);//save matched value in an array
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  // setting saved track data in the "P"  (16) column
  student.getRange(2, 16, tracks.length, 1).setValues(tracks);
}
```

You can check your sheets' associated code ("GPA") for alternations.